Required quantity not meeting demand
I am working on a cutting stock problem, here is the formulation. Even if I have unlimited patterns, why model is not meeting demand fully.



WHat do you mean by "why model is not meeting demand fully"? Do you have any proof that for any instance the demand constraint won't be satisfied? Or, you have a specific instance for this?
